# Is "aha" an appropriate answer to "thank you"?

Tags: formality, conversation

I have heard many native speakers in the United states answer with a brief and cold "aha" when someone says "thank you".  Is it really appropriate to answer like that? I myself feel offended when I receive such a response from a teacher or someone I don't know.

Comment: It seems to depend on the intonation and facial expression. It may also be a wave of dismissal, like the Spanish response _De nada_ (literally, 'of nothing'), or the American _Don't mention it, Think nothing of it, It was nothing_). Manners are different in every culture; no doubt some of yours are bothering Americans, too, but they're too polite to mention it.

Comment: Oh, and I don't understand your last sentence at all; it appears to be put together from parts that don't fit.

Comment: Related: *[How do native English speakers respond to “Thank you”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2516/)*, *[Different ways to say “you're welcome”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/42697)*, *[Can “Sure” be used to respond to “Thanks”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/35055)*, and *[What happened to “You're welcome?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/212215)*

Comment: Further related:  *[What is the meaning of “don't mention it” (in response to “thank you”)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/34931)*, *[Is it right to say “Thank you” in the response of “Thank you”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/49315)*, *[Is “not at all” still alive and doing well?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1265)*

Comment: In addition to the previous examples of "don't mention it", I often times hear people say "Yep" or "You betcha".  It's an idiomatic expression.

Answer (score 11):

I think what you are actually hearing is a short, simple "uh-huh", which is intended as an acknowledgement that they have received your thanks and consider the exchange complete.  It is not intended to be rude; in fact, ignoring someone who says "thanks" is much ruder.  It's very informal, and is probably mostly used when whatever answer they gave that prompted you to thank them was a small, barely noteworthy thing.

Other utterances that you may hear include:

- Sure
- yup
- you bet
- no prob
- mm-hmm (or even just mmm)
- (a head nod)

Comment: This. And don't forget *mm-hmm* as well.

Comment: I knew I'd forgotten one.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

**Edited** [The original post asked for *ah*, not *aha*.]

To a peer or a social inferior, *aha* may indeed be appropriate in casual situations— in fact, a mere *mmm* or wave of the hand would be sufficient. It is an acknowledgement of the thanks, but simultaneously a dismissal of it as if it were unnecessary.

I almost never hear *you're welcome*, the conventional response, except in more formal situations or where the respondent is expressing an extra level of deference (for instance, if I thank a waitress for her attentive service).

---

**Original**

I don't know any Americans who would say *[ah](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/ah)* (/ä/), but I know some who might dismiss it with a *mmm* or *uh-huh* or *eh* (/e/), accompanied by a nod or shrug or wave of the hand, in casual exchanges with a peer.

Note that this *eh* is different from *[eh](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/eh)* (/eɪ/) the interjection used to express surprise or seek agreement. It rhymes with, and can sometimes be interchanged with, *[meh](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/meh)*.

---

There are [numerous ways an English speaker may reply to a "thank-you"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2516) and the intent is almost never to offend; however, due to cultural differences, it seems that responses like *eh* or *[no problem](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146671)* seem to offend some.

The eh-er is trying to express that whatever it is that inspired the expression of thanks was a small matter, and that the thankful person should therefore not feel that he or she has any obligations on account of it, thus *don't worry about it*, *it's no big [deal]*, *no worries*, *no bother*, *not at all*, *don't mention it*, and so on.

Comment: I would not use *meh* to say thank you unless what I offered was of questionable value. To me, *meh* is kind of shorthand for "Yeah, well . . ."

Comment: @Robusto Not ever for *thank you*, but certainly for *you're welcome*. *Naw* or *Nahh* is another.

Comment: Yeah, I gather from some Millennial communications that I've intercepted that "meh" is dismissive, and would therefore not be a polite response to "Thank you".

Comment: I don't see an *un-hunh* or a *sure* as a dismissal- rather it's a succinct acknowledgement or acceptance of the thanks given.

Answer (score 0):

I tell you that aha is much more respectable than no response at all , it is American normal way of responding to thank you , I am myself not originally American , I notice that mostly non-Americans are offended by this normal aha , I had a non-American friend who was going really crazy if americans said aha after he said thanks ...I am sure if he had a compilation video of how americans usually respond to thank you , he would be no more mad at hearing aha